# Virtual Box hanging

Tags: virtualbox

I've been running Windows 10 in Virtual Box for a good few months now but all of a sudden when I try to start it up it's hanging. It gets as far as opening the virtual box window then after a second or less the whole laptop freezes and I have to do a hard boot, no error messages to go on.  Can anybody suggest why this should suddenly happen, I don't think I've changed anything. 
I've also tried re-installing everything ( Virtual  Box and a new vdi ) but it still hangs when I try to re-install.
I'm running Windows inside Ubuntu 16.04 and version 5.0.40 of Virtual Box
 Thanks.

Comment: Extremely hard to debug when there are no errors. I assume you had fully upgraded the host 16.04. LTS OS and VirtualBox (5.2.4. at present). Then try with a bit fewer memory or CPU cores for the VM.

Comment: Strangely - or maybe it gives a clue -   when I try to install latest version of V Box the install exhibits similar characteristics to when I was trying to start up Windows in VB. It thinks about installing for a moment and then gives up - or is that because there's something additional I need to download ?